# Recyclerview inside Recyclerview inside RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview

I have to implement nested RecyclerViews. A RecyclerView inside RecyclerView inside RecyclerView.I searched for this but there are example of only 2 nested RecyclerView. Is nesting of three RecyclerViews possible?

Comment: what's keeping you from trying?

Comment: I tried but this is happening.I need three recycler views one for course, one for chapters in course and one for tracks in chapter. All the three recycler views are initializing but the recycler view of chapter is showing only one chapter in the course and tracks of that chapter but it is not showing the second chapter. After showing first chapter and its tracks, It shows second course and its first chapter and its tracks and so on. only first item of middle recyclerview is showing not all the items.